# Cell Broadcast message in Florence

Tags: italy, cellphones, florence

Was in Florence a couple about a month ago and I think I got about 10 cell broadcast messages with the content `FI32402`.

Searching google proved to be pretty pointless and I assume that the FI part stands for Firenze, the rest is a complete mystery.

Anyone good any ideas about what it could mean?[image: Screenshoot]

**Update 1**

- My phone had two different sims, both prepaid from EU (Vodafone DE and Orange RO) but none from Italy so was in roaming with both.
- Traveled to other cities in Italy but didn't receive any other messages.
- Can not remember which provider I was using while in Florence.

**Update 2**

- Was there with someone else who also had two sims one from Vodafone RO and another from LaPoste FR and didn't receive any messages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about cell phone service, not travel.

Comment: Could this be a fit for [networking.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) or Super User?

Comment: @DavidRicherby this isn't really a technical question, I understand how the cell broadcast system works. I just don't understand what the message means, and I think the message is specific to Florence. If there a better suited StackExchange site for the question?

Comment: A long time ago I remember that at least some Swiss networks used cell broadcast to send information about the cell you were attached to (I think it was more than just an ID, it included the name of the location as well IIRC). Just informative, and not especially useful. It **may** have been useful to allow you to dial local numbers without regional prefix, though. But at the times phones (good old 2G Nokias) just displayed the message without a need for confirmation.

Comment: @BobbyTables note that there isn't always a suitable SE site. It doesn't cover every single topic, yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's mroe suited for networking or superuser.